# while calling a constructor from copy constructor it calls destructor too

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, copy-constructor

I ve made a program that uses copy constructor to copy the object. In copy constructor i ve called the constructor to create memory and copy the contents. It does that successfully in constructor but immediately after the constructor ends destructor is called and i get the garbage value. At last in the main function if i make any attempts to destroy the newly created object the program crashes. why it behaves like that?

here's the code.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test
{
    public:
    int a;
    int *p;

    Test(int a,int b,int c)
    {
        this->a=a;
        p=new int[2];
        p[0]=b;
        p[1]=c;
        cout<<"\n\n "<<this->a<<"   "<<this->p[0]<<"   "<<this->p[1];
    }
    Test(const Test &ob)
    {
        Test(ob.a,ob.p[0],ob.p[1]);
        cout<<"\n\n "<<this->a<<"   "<<this->p[0]<<"   "<<this->p[1];
    }
    void print()
    {
        cout<<"\n\n\n "<<a<<"   "<<p[0]<<"   "<<p[1];
    }
    ~Test()
    {
        cout<<"\n\n\n DESTRUCTOR CALLED "<<endl;
        delete [] p;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test *ob1=new Test(2,3,4);
    cout<<"\n\n\n  ob2: new object";
    Test *ob2=new Test(*ob1);
    cout<<"\n\n\n ob1";
    (*ob1).print();
    cout<<"\n\n\n ob2";
    (*ob2).print();
    delete ob1;
    delete ob2;
    return 1;
}
```

produces the output:

2   3   4

ob2: new object
2   3   4

DESTRUCTOR CALLED

9968956   9968956   0

ob1

2   3   4

ob2

9968956   9968956   0

DESTRUCTOR CALLED

DESTRUCTOR CALLED

"then the program stops working i.e. crashes"....

i understoood what happens in this case but plz explain me why the program crashes in this case when the object ob2 is deleted.
thanks

Comment: What do you actually want to achive with `Test(ob.a,ob.p[0],ob.p[1]);`? Sounds like a XY problem to me.

Comment: What does `p=new int(2*sizeof(int));` do?  You probably meant `p=new int[2];`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here, at least.

Firstly, `int* p` is a pointer to a single integer, but you're treating it like a pointer to an array of integers. `p[1]` is not necessarily memory that you own.

Regarding your unexpected destructor invocation, your copy constructor creates a temporary `Test` object which gets destroyed when you exit the scope of your copy constructor. This is why you're seeing your destructor called right after trying to create a new object from copy construction. Please see @songyuanyao's answer regarding using delegate constructors.

Additionally, your calls to `delete` have no effect because they are placed after your call to `return`.

Finally, just as a stylistic note, `return 0;` usually indicates that your program ended normally. `return <some_nonzero_number>;` is typically used to indicate to the invoker that your program ended due to some error.

Edit: `p=new int(2*sizeof(int));` is still not what you want to do to use `p` as you're trying to use it. This simply creates a pointer to a single integer, where the integer has a value of 2 * 4 = 8.
To use `p` properly, you probably mean `p = new int[2];` Remember to use `delete [] p;` in your destructor in this case.

Comment: Not only `p = new int[2];` in ctor, and `delete[] p;` in dtor.

Comment: and a deep copy in the copy ctor. Or avoid it all with RAII

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit OP's trying to do deep copy, if he called delegate constructor successfully, and the constructor allocate memory correctly.

Comment: @songyuanyao: Right, and it's the "if" we're making sure happens.

Answer (score 4):

The copy constructor does nothing indeed. `Test(ob.a,ob.p[0],ob.p[1]);` is just creating a temporary `Test`, which will be destroyed immediately. All the members of `Test` are not initialized at all.

You want [delegate constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list#Delegating_constructor), which is a C++11 feature.

```
Test(const Test &ob) : Test(ob.a, ob.p[0], ob.p[1])
{
    cout<<"\n\n "<<this->a<<"   "<<this->p[0]<<"   "<<this->p[1];
}
```

Comment: To add to @songyuanyao's prompt answer, the program crashes when you try to delete the 2nd object because your class attribute "p" is never created, so deleting causes a crash.

Comment: If you can't use delegate constructors, you can still initialize the individual members in the initializer list.